# Eigenvector of canonical form matrix

Tags: matrices, ordinary-differential-equations, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

So if you have the canonical matrix:

$$
\begin{pmatrix}
\lambda &1\\
0 & \lambda
\end{pmatrix}
$$
the eigenvector is $(1,0)$. I've found this from multiple sources. But where does that come from?

Thanks to any who answer!

Comment: I guess I mean how would you go about calculating the actual eigenvector in the first place. But the generalized eigenvector makes a lot of sense. Since you have a repeated eigenvalue.

Comment: Welcome to MSE!  [Here is a guide on formatting.](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: No the original matrix is not edited into my original question. It's in canonical form. The lamdas are just the arbitrary eigenvalues. And yes. It should be (0,-1)

Comment: However the matrix you gave would be a valid example of that. So that works! Sorry for my lack of clarity. Trying my best to express my question correctly

Comment: Okay. I was looking at the system wrong. Thank you so much for your patience!

Comment: You should put it in an "answer" so I can upvote you. Thanks again!